# Issue with image import process using VHD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I am having issue with importing vhd imagaes and getting the below error in logs -
can someone pleas advise on the exact issue and steps to be taken.

`starting build "32b9fa2e-5b24-4f92-bc0b-a385a39de4fe"`

```
FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Pulling image: gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release
release: Pulling from compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import
32f8bd955290: Pulling fs layer
01ed8fd8ea7d: Pulling fs layer
9725b749501b: Pulling fs layer
96ebe2242ea6: Pulling fs layer
7ea060874995: Pulling fs layer
330214355a8a: Pulling fs layer
6a0db923c4a2: Pulling fs layer
d548baee13a0: Pulling fs layer
96ebe2242ea6: Waiting
7ea060874995: Waiting
330214355a8a: Waiting
6a0db923c4a2: Waiting
d548baee13a0: Waiting
9725b749501b: Verifying Checksum
9725b749501b: Download complete
96ebe2242ea6: Verifying Checksum
96ebe2242ea6: Download complete
01ed8fd8ea7d: Verifying Checksum
01ed8fd8ea7d: Download complete
7ea060874995: Verifying Checksum
7ea060874995: Download complete
32f8bd955290: Verifying Checksum
32f8bd955290: Download complete
d548baee13a0: Verifying Checksum
d548baee13a0: Download complete
330214355a8a: Verifying Checksum
330214355a8a: Download complete
6a0db923c4a2: Verifying Checksum
6a0db923c4a2: Download complete
32f8bd955290: Pull complete
01ed8fd8ea7d: Pull complete
9725b749501b: Pull complete
96ebe2242ea6: Pull complete
7ea060874995: Pull complete
330214355a8a: Pull complete
6a0db923c4a2: Pull complete
d548baee13a0: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b6b9af6f75715335bf7e26d124db4dc12d00802b9b90d4cedcb6109e9229c6c9
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release
gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:45.876Z Creating scratch bucket `ti-ds-tii-02-daisy-bkt-asia-south1` in ASIA-SOUTH1 region
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:50Z Validating workflow
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:50Z Validating step "setup-disks"
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:50Z Validating step "import-virtual-disk"
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Validating step "wait-for-signal"
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Validating step "cleanup"
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Validation Complete
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Workflow Project: ti-ds-tii-02
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Workflow Zone: asia-south1-c
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Workflow GCSPath: gs://ti-ds-tii-02-daisy-bkt-asia-south1/gce-image-import-2020-11-14T18:29:42Z-9lr5g
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Daisy scratch path: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ti-ds-tii-02-daisy-bkt-asia-south1/gce-image-import-2020-11-14T18:29:42Z-9lr5g/daisy-import-image-20201114-18:29:50-6njmt
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:51Z Uploading sources
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:52Z Running workflow
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:29:52Z Running step "setup-disks" (CreateDisks)
[import-image.setup-disks]: 2020-11-14T18:29:52Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-importer-import-image-6njmt".
[import-image.setup-disks]: 2020-11-14T18:29:52Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-9lr5g".
[import-image.setup-disks]: 2020-11-14T18:29:52Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-import-image-scratch-6njmt".
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:30:06Z Step "setup-disks" (CreateDisks) successfully finished.
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:30:06Z Running step "import-virtual-disk" (CreateInstances)
[import-image.import-virtual-disk]: 2020-11-14T18:30:06Z CreateInstances: Creating instance "inst-importer-import-image-6njmt".
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:30:14Z Error running workflow: step "import-virtual-disk" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2020-11-14T10:30:14.723-08:00 Error:0xc0004bef00 HttpErrorMessage:FORBIDDEN HttpErrorStatusCode:403 Id:7304694042046864607 InsertTime:2020-11-14T10:30:08.214-08:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-1605378606684-5b4155594d8c3-a29dc660-d173e76c OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ti-ds-tii-02/zones/asia-south1-c/operations/operation-1605378606684-5b4155594d8c3-a29dc660-d173e76c StartTime:2020-11-14T10:30:08.217-08:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:4431756053719129280 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ti-ds-tii-02/zones/asia-south1-c/instances/inst-importer-import-image-6njmt User:219724526694@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ti-ds-tii-02/zones/asia-south1-c ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Sat, 14 Nov 2020 18:30:14 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}: 
Code: QUOTA_EXCEEDED
Message: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1.
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:30:14Z Workflow "import-image" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[import-image]: 2020-11-14T18:30:16Z Workflow "import-image" finished cleanup.
CANCELLED
ERROR: context canceled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem is related to Quotas and limits,
This is the important part:

```
Quota 'CPUS' exceeded.  Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1.
```

You might need to raise a request first to increase this resource quota (CPUS in region `asia-south1`) before you can  continue with your import process.

To submit a Quota Increase request you could follow the [next steps:](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota)

1. Go to the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.224635738.1947912715.1605536697-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.216553060.1605566016.Cj0KCQiA48j9BRC-ARIsAMQu3WTFIy4A-fKcjrK2AgEUEGEFOijOShOrATbMcixohdGajU9VztkOyyUaAhrQEALw_wcB) page

[image]

2. In the **Quotas** page, select the quotas you want to change in your case should be CPUS in region `asia-south1`.
3. Click the **Edit Quotas** button on the top of the page.
   [image]
4. Check the box of the service you want to edit.
5. Fill out your name, email, and phone number, and click **Next**.
6. Enter your request to increase your quota, and click **Next**.
7. Then submit your request.

Take in consideration that the resolution of your request could take from 24 to 48 hours.